# Is it possible to configure activator to reload the build.sbt when changed?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

Is there any configuration or parameter that when running `activator run` on a PlayFramework project make the SBT monitor the `build.sbt` file such as any other file in your project?

So when you change it and refresh your page it will reload the build.sbt and compile what need to be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no...

`activator ui` mode kind of does this, but it has to stop the play http server as it reboots sbt, so it isn't just a browser reload, it's change build.sbt, wait a bit for restart, and then browser reload.

In command line mode like `activator run`, under the hood the issue is that to reload build.sbt the entire build has to reload, and the running http server is "inside" the build so also has to be restarted. In the UI, the UI stays running so it can take care of restarting the http server, but in command line mode there's nothing "outside" to do this.